# Limiting XML read to 5 records

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file with 100 records, but I want it to limit it to just 5 records

```
for ($i=0;$i<=5;$i++) {
   foreach($xml->entry as $result){ 

            if ($result->updated == $result->published) {
                    }
    }
}
```

When I put in the above code, it display one record 5 times.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = 0;
foreach($xml->entry as $result)
{
   if ($result->updated == $result->published) {
   }

   $count++;    
   if ($count++ == 5) break;
   // if ($count++ == 5) break; think this might work aswell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the foreach loop runs only once, because there is only one `entry`, and the for loop prints it 5 times. If there were more than one, this code would print each entry 5 times. If `$xml->entry` is an array, you can do it like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $result = $xml->entry[$i];

    if($result->updated == $result->published) {
    }
}
```

Check if there are more than one `<entry>` tags in your XML file.